# How to draw curved text using MFC functions?

Tags: winapi, mfc

How to draw curved text using MFC functions? I want to achieve like this below.

[image]

DrawText() function draws text in straight line only, I do not know how to draw curved text at particular angle. Please help me.

Thanks.

Comment: [SetWorldTransform](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-setworldtransform). You may have to switch to using `TextOut()` function as I have a feeling `DrawText()` doesn't support transformations.

Comment: @Jonathan, For my scenario, how to construct XForm for SetWorldTransform and how to calculate x, y position for TextOut().

Comment: That's a maths question, not a programming question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use GDI+, There is a sample in [code project](https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/816791/how-to-draw-text-around-the-circle-in-Csharp), which is written in C#, I translate it into C++:

```
    Graphics graphics(hWnd);

    RECT rect = { 0 };
    GetWindowRect(hWnd, &rect);
    POINT center = { (rect.right - rect.left) / 2,(rect.bottom - rect.top) / 2 };
    double radius = min(rect.right - rect.left, (rect.bottom - rect.top)) / 3;
    TCHAR text[] = L"ABCDEFGHIJLKMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    REAL emSize = 24;
    Font* font = new Font(FontFamily::GenericSansSerif(), emSize, FontStyleBold);
    for (int i = 0; i < _tcslen(text); ++i)
    {
        RectF re, in;
        Status result = graphics.MeasureString(&text[i], 1, font, in, &re);;

        double charRadius = radius + re.Height;

        double angle = (((float)i / _tcslen(text)) - 0.25) * 2 * M_PI;

        double x = (int)(center.x + cos(angle) * charRadius);
        double y = (int)(center.y + sin(angle) * charRadius);


        result = graphics.TranslateTransform(x, y);

        result = graphics.RotateTransform((float)(90 + 360 * angle / (2 * M_PI)));
        PointF start(0, 0);
        SolidBrush Red(Color(255, 255, 0, 0));
        result = graphics.DrawString(&text[i], 1, font, start, &Red);

        result = graphics.ResetTransform();

        SolidBrush Green(Color(255, 0, 255, 0));
        Pen* pen = new Pen(&Green, 2.0f);
        result = graphics.DrawArc(pen, (REAL)(center.x - radius), (REAL)(center.y - radius), radius * 2, radius * 2, 0, 360);
    }
```

Some header files:

```
#define _USE_MATH_DEFINES
#include <math.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <objidl.h>
#include <gdiplus.h>
using namespace Gdiplus;
#pragma comment (lib,"Gdiplus.lib")
```

Usage:

> You must call `GdiplusStartup` before you create any GDI+ objects, and
>   you must delete all of your GDI+ objects (or have them go out of
>   scope) before you call `GdiplusShutdown`.

```
GdiplusStartupInput gdiplusStartupInput;
ULONG_PTR gdiplusToken;
GdiplusStartup(&gdiplusToken, &gdiplusStartupInput, NULL);
//To Do.
GdiplusShutdown(gdiplusToken);
```

Result:

[image]

UPDATE:

```
    Graphics graphics(hWnd);

    RECT rect = { 0 };
    GetWindowRect(hWnd, &rect);
    POINT center = { (rect.right - rect.left) / 2,(rect.bottom - rect.top) / 2 };
    double radius = min(rect.right - rect.left, (rect.bottom - rect.top)) / 3;
    TCHAR text[72][4] = { 0 };
    for (int i = 0; i < 72; i++)
    {
         _itot((i/2)*10, text[i],10);
         i++;
         _tcscpy(text[i],L"");
    }
    REAL emSize = 8;
    Font* font = new Font(FontFamily::GenericSansSerif(), emSize, FontStyleBold);
    for (int i = 0; i < 72; ++i)
    {
        RectF re, in,rel;
        Status result = graphics.MeasureString(text[i], _tcslen(text[i]), font, in, &re);
        result = graphics.MeasureString(L"|", 1, font, in, &rel);
        double charRadius = radius - re.Height;

        double angle = (((float)i / 72) - 0.25) * 2 * M_PI;

        double x = (center.x + cos(angle) * charRadius);
        double y = (center.y + sin(angle) * charRadius);


        result = graphics.TranslateTransform(x, y);

        result = graphics.RotateTransform((float)(90 + 360 * angle / (2 * M_PI)));
        PointF start(0- re.Width/2, 0);
        SolidBrush Red(Color(255, 255, 0, 0));
        result = graphics.DrawString(text[i], _tcslen(text[i]), font, start, &Red);
        result = graphics.ResetTransform();

        x = (int)(center.x + cos(angle) * radius);
        y = (int)(center.y + sin(angle) * radius);
        result = graphics.TranslateTransform(x, y);
        result = graphics.RotateTransform((float)(90 + 360 * angle / (2 * M_PI)));

        PointF start1(0 - rel.Width / 2, 0);
        result = graphics.DrawString(L"|", 1, font, start1, &Red);
        result = graphics.ResetTransform();
    }
    SolidBrush Green(Color(255, 0, 255, 0));
    Pen* pen = new Pen(&Green, 2.0f);
    Status result = graphics.DrawArc(pen, (REAL)(center.x - radius), (REAL)(center.y - radius), radius * 2, radius * 2, 0, 360);
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: I could not understand this angle/radian calculation double angle = (((float)i / 72) - 0.25) * 2 * M_PI; result = graphics.RotateTransform((float)(90 + 360 * angle / (2 * M_PI))); please expalin me.

Comment: It calculates the coordinates of the ith character, and rotate the axis in degrees. This is actually a triangle transformation. The following formula gives the same coordinates and angles: 
`double angle = (((float)i / 72)) * 2 * M_PI;
double x = (center.x + sin(angle) * charRadius);
double y = (center.y - cos(angle) * charRadius);
result = graphics.RotateTransform((float)(360 * angle / (2 * M_PI)));`